# Java count between timestamps for large databases inserts

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, postgresql, timestamp

I have a java program that is connected to a MQTT broker. I need to insert a row for each incoming message  from the broker.

**Messages table schema**

```
   Column   |              Type              |                     Modifiers
------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------
 content    | character(255)                 |
 user_id    | character(255)                 |
 sent_at    | timestamp(6) without time zone | default ('now'::text)::timestamp(6) with time zone
 message_id | character(255)                 |
 status     | character(1)                   | default 'w'::bpchar
```

**I need to keep track of messages between a time interval.**

My main java application establish a db connection and contains a MQTT listener, which insert a row for each incoming new message.

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws     Exception {
                //System.out.println("New Msg");
                //System.out.println(s);
                insertMessage(mqttMessage);

}
```

Message insertion method

```
/***
 *
 * @param mqttMessage
 */
private static void insertMessage(MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
    arrived++ ;
    try {
        String mysql = "insert into messages (content, message_id, user_id, sent_at, status) values ('" + mqttMessage.getPayload() + "',  " + arrived + ", " + arrived + ", " + " CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (6) " + ", " + "'w'" + ") RETURNING sent_at";
        //System.out.println (mysql);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(mysql);
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            // Log the last timestamp
             System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.out.println("Failed !");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println(arrived);
}
```

In the same program, i implemented a java class  which has it's  **db connection** and keep **latestTimestamp** .

I use `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` to check the count of messages inserted between for every 10 seconds and update the latest timestamp.
The method of getting last inserted timestamp  is :

```
/**
 * Used to update the latest value from the db
 */
private void updateTimestamp() throws SQLException {
    //timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery( "select sent_at from messages  order by sent_at  desc  limit 1 ;");
    if (resultSet.next()) {
//   Supposed to be the latest inserted row and the latest timestamp in the db
        latestTimestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(1);
        System.out.print("new timestamp ==> ");
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    } else {
        timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(Constants.MIN_TIMESTAMP_VALUE);
    }
}
```

and then when i need to get the messages count that has been inserted after the latest date updated i use a query that compare the timestamp.

```
/**
 * This function get all messages that have been sent from latest timestamp
 *
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private ResultSet getMQTTMessagesDelayed() throws SQLException {
    oldTimeStamp = latestTimestamp ;
    // Update the new timestamp to reduce losing time in execution
    updateTimestamp();
    mysql = "Select count(*) as cn from messages where  sent_at > '" + oldTimeStamp  + "' ;";
    System.out.println(mysql);
    return statement.executeQuery(mysql);

}
```

The problem now, that for a large count of messages starting from ~5000, i expect to have the correct some of messages when calculating the sum of select count , for example, if i send a bulk 5000ms, when the scheduled thread execute and gets 2500  as count for this time, i need to get 2500 for the next epoch time (next 10 sec), **which is not the case** and i get some incorrect results (getting around 45/20 in difference !).

**Note**

- Tested with MysqL and postgres
- 8 GB RAM
- Windows 10
- Java 8

Answer (score 2):

With two threads running in parallel, one inserts and the other selects  both from the same table, you will hardly ever get a predictable result and your performance may degrade as the messages table grows. My understanding is that you only want to keep the count of messages inserted between two given dates. And these dates are within an interval which is rather short (10 secs). Therefore, I think that it would be much better if you keep track of the incoming messages with an in-memory List in which oldest elements are discarded at scheduled intervals by a worker thread.

Also, you do not need to retrieve a ResultSet from the INSERT. Instead, it would be much faster to generate sent_at Date field at client site and then pass it into the INSERT SQL statement using either a PreparedStatement parameter or STR_TO_DATE MySQL function or { ts 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS' } standard JDBC escape syntax for dates.

Your `insertMessage` would then become

```
private static void insertMessage(MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
    arrived++ ;
    try {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");         
        String mysql = "insert into messages (content, message_id, user_id, sent_at, status) values ('" + mqttMessage.getPayload() + "',  " + arrived + ", " + arrived + ", { ts '" + fmt.format(now)  + "' }, " + "'w'" + ")";
        statement.executeUpdate(mysql);
        messageList.add(now);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and (assuming that you only have one writer thread) a sample implementation for the list keeping track of the incoming messages something like

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MessageList implements AutoCloseable {

    private List<Date> messages;
    private CleanUp cleaner;

    private final long MAX_KEEP_TRACK = 20l;
    private final long RUN_EVERY_SECS = 10l;

    public MessageList() {
        messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Date>());
        cleaner = new CleanUp(messages, MAX_KEEP_TRACK, RUN_EVERY_SECS);
        cleaner.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {      
        cleaner.stop();
    }

    public void add(Date messageDate) {
        messages.add(messageDate);
    }

    public int countBetween(Date start, Date end) {
        int count =0;
        for (Date d : messages) {
            if (d.compareTo(end)>0) {
                break;
            } else if (d.compareTo(start)>=0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private class CleanUp extends Thread {

        private List<Date> msgs;
        private long maxKeepMilis;
        private long runEveryMilis;
        private boolean stop;

        public CleanUp(List<Date> messages, long maxKeepSecs, long runEverySecs) {
            msgs = messages;
            maxKeepMilis = maxKeepSecs * 1000l;
            runEveryMilis = runEverySecs * 1000l;
            stop = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Date d;
            while(!stop) {
                long now = new Date().getTime();
                while ((d=msgs.get(0))!=null)
                    if (now-d.getTime()>maxKeepMilis)
                        msgs.remove(0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(runEveryMilis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you just call `messageList.countBetween()` to get the count of messages received between two dates.

Comment: thank you for your investigation.
I have two notes :
- As I have a huge number of messages (bulk) that come in short interval, i set the TIMESTAMP with 6 digits precision "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS"
-  I thing that generating the time in the client side is a bad idea as you can not control its behavior. 
For your solution, i'm interested in the count and the content as i wait the client to reply to my message. So keeping it in memory may cause a lot of time to find the client message from the list, so that's why i use the database so can another thread listen to clients replies.

Comment: While probably no two messages will have the same yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS you cannot actually grant that. What I would do is to have a long which is incremented on each insert. Then concatenate the Date.getTime() of the message with the long and use both as unique message identifier. With a single writer on a single machine that will grant you message id. uniqueness. And even if you reboot the machine and the counter is reseted to zero you won't get duplicates. Then you can still use the message timestamp to get a count by date interval ignoring the long counter part of the message id.

Comment: Last, if you really have a huge number of messages incoming, you may consider queuing them and then inserting into batches from a different thread using PreparedStatement.addBatch() PreparedStatement.executeBatch()